# Unable to figure out how to do Dependency Injection or Auto-wiring in a Strategy Pattern design

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I have implemented a strategy pattern for which I am looking forward to use Spring's dependency injection .

I have following use case :

```
class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private Interface behaviour ;
    private String someData;
    // getters setters 

    public void doBehaviour(){
        this.behaviour.doBehaviour(someData); // getting null pointer here
    }
}

public Interface IBehaviour {
    void doBehaviour(String someData);
}
@Component
class MyCustomBehaviour1 implements IBehaviour {



    @Override
    void doBehaviour(String ){
        System.out.println("Playing with MyCustomBehaviour1 -> " + someData);
    }

}

My Main class -

public Main {
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    Controller ctrln = new Controller();
    ctrln.setBehaviour(); 
    ctrln.doBehaviour(); 
}
```

How can I efficiently do Autowiring / Depenedency Injection in this case or how can i Improve this code ? I am new to Spring so Unable to figure out Autowiring part because of the association between Interface Implementation and controller class

> Edit : Removed circular association

It Worked after getting Controller object from spring bean cycle instead of creating an object of our own .

Comment: Your code has a cyclic dependency that is bad... You should write code without cyclic dependencies.

Comment: @M.Deinum removed circular association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should remove cyclic dependency here. 
One suggestion is remove `private Interface behaviour ;` from Controller class and call `doBehaviour` somewhere outside the Controller class.

And once you are done with that then you can move into Autowiring. The basic is in order to Autowire, spring context need a bean of that particular class type. There are several ways to do that according to your class you can just put

```
@Component
class Controller {
```

@Component annotion.

> Note : In your application class There should be a
>   `@ComponentScan("relevant.package")` indicating spring context to where to find your beans.

And once you have created your bean, then you can Autowire it as follows,

```
@Component
class MyCustomBehaviour1 implements IBehaviour {

// instance of controller 
private Controller cntrlInstanceToUseData;

@Autowired
public MyCustomBehaviour (Controller ctrlInst){
    this.cntrlInstanceToUseData = ctrlInst;
}

@Override
void doBehaviour(){
    System.out.println("Playing with MyCustomBehaviour1 -> " + cntrlInstanceToUseData.getSommeData());
}
}
```

Now you really no need to create Controller object and Behaviour Object, Accessing doBehaviour should be done where ever you want by using

```
@Autowire
private IBehaviour myBehaviour
```

For more information please [read](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire)

Comment: Please see my comment now ,I understood your this solution but how to autowire an implemntation of an Interface. I have editted mine question

Comment: You can see that I have annotated your MyCusyomBehaviour1 class as a component which implements your behaviour interface. So when autowiring, you are not autowiring an interface, you are autowiring the implementation of particular class to the interface reference. Basically the abstraction in OOP concepts. And yes spring is capable of identifying the relevant bean. If there are multiple beans and you need to explicitly mention which one you need to autowire, have a look at @Qualifier annotation

Comment: I updated my code  and getting a null pointer exception .please check

Comment: where do you get nullpointer? and did you notice my Note in the answer ? Adding @ComponentScan("relevant.package") ??

Comment: Yes I have added COmponnentScan with package name , getting null pointer in doBehaviour() of Controller .please check updated code

Comment: The problem here is you are creating the controller class instance by yourself and its not being created spring context, so in that case Autowire will not work. so your variable behaviour will be null. You need to annotate your controller class as a @Component and in your application class, dont create new object of it, instead lookup the spring context for a bean of that class type and use it. This should fix your problem

Comment: how will i do this - "instead lookup the spring context for a bean"

Comment: AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
Controller controller = context.getBean(Controller.class);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180919/discussion-between-divyanshu-jimmy-and-damith).